# how to make central area resize to QDockWidgets positions

Tags: c++, qt, resize, center, qdockwidget

Since it seems not possible to add a QDockWidget in the middle area of a form, i wonder how can i resize the middle area text widget to automatically will the space.

Ex:

```
=======================
|    top doc          |
|---------------------| 
| left| text    |right|
| dock|  edit   |doc  |
|     |         |     |
|     |         |     |
=======================
```

now if i resize or move any docks, it doesnt resize the text edit in the middle. How can i make my text edit automatically resizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make the text edit the central widget, then it should have this behaviour by default

see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html

Comment: Doesnt work for layouts throught, but using some default container then adding a layout works.